# Show $\vdash (\phi \to \psi) \land (\lnot \phi \to \psi) \to \psi$.

Tags: logic, solution-verification, natural-deduction

Note: $\lnot \phi$ is an abbreviation of $\phi \to \bot$. Using Dirk van Dalen. "*Logic and Structure (Universitext)*" as reference book.

**Derivation:**

$
\def\be{\mathsf{\tiny{\leftrightarrow} Elim}}
\def\bi{\mathsf{\tiny{\leftrightarrow} Intro}}
\def\ce{\mathsf{\tiny{\land} Elim}}
\def\ne#1{\mathsf{\tiny\neg Elim^{#1 }}}
\def\ni#1{\mathsf{\tiny\neg Intro^{#1}}}
\def\ii#1{\mathsf{\tiny{\to}Intro^{#1}}}
\def\ie{\mathsf{\tiny{\to}Elim}}
\def\RAA#1{\mathsf{\tiny RAA^{#1}}}
$

$
\dfrac{
  \dfrac{
      \dfrac{
        \dfrac{
          \dfrac{
            \dfrac{}{[\lnot \psi]_3}\dfrac{
              \dfrac{}{[\phi]_2}\dfrac{
                [(\phi \to \psi) \land (\lnot \phi \to \psi)]_1
              }{\phi \to \psi}\ce
            }{\psi}\ie
          }{\bot}\ie
        }{\lnot \phi}\ni 2
      \dfrac{
        [(\phi \to \psi) \land (\lnot \phi \to \psi)]_1
      }{\lnot \phi \to \psi}\ce
    }{\psi}\RAA 3 \dfrac{}{[\lnot \psi]_4}
  }{\psi}\ne 4
}{(\phi \to \psi) \land (\lnot \phi \to \psi) \to \psi}\ii 1
$

My questions are:

- Is the hypotesis of $\lnot \psi$ labeled with a sub-index "4" correctly discharged ?
- Is this proof correct ?

EDIT:

**Revised derivation:**

$
\dfrac{
  \dfrac{
      \dfrac{
        \dfrac{
        \dfrac{
          \dfrac{
            \dfrac{}{[\lnot \psi]_3}\dfrac{
              \dfrac{}{[\phi]_2}\dfrac{
                [(\phi \to \psi) \land (\lnot \phi \to \psi)]_1
              }{\phi \to \psi}\ce
            }{\psi}\ie
          }{\bot}\ie
        }{\lnot \phi}\ii 2
      \dfrac{
        [(\phi \to \psi) \land (\lnot \phi \to \psi)]_1
      }{\lnot \phi \to \psi}\ce
    }{\psi}\ie \dfrac{}{[\lnot \psi]_3}
      }{\bot}\ie
  }{\psi}\RAA 3
}{(\phi \to \psi) \land (\lnot \phi \to \psi) \to \psi}\ii 1
$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your derivation up until $\neg \phi, \neg \phi \to \psi$ as well as the very last step are correct. Your idea that we need to get rid of the assumption $\neg \psi$ and for that purpose provoke a contradiction in order to then apply $RAA$ thereby discharging the assumption is also correct, but you got the rules a bit mixed up there.
The next step which combines $\neg \phi$ and $\neg \phi \to \psi$ to yield $\psi$ is not RAA, but $\to Elim$. This rule does not allow to discharge assumptions and we still need to get rid of the assumption $\neg \psi$. So even though we already established the desired conclusion $\psi$, we need to make a detour with further steps in order to kill the remaining assumption along the way.
Performing a $\neg Elim$ with assumption $\neg \psi$ first leads to $\bot$. From that you can then conclude $\psi$ by an application of $RAA$, thereby discharging both occurrences of the assumption $\neg \psi$ (the one that was still open from earlier and the one we just opened).
This allows you to then complete the proof with $\to Intro$.

```
[-psi]3
  ...            ...
 -phi        -phi -> psi
------------------------- (-> E)
           psi                     [-psi]3
          ------------------------------ (- E)
                        ⊥
                       --- (RAA)3
                       psi            
     ------------------------------------- (-> I)1
      (phi -> psi) ^ (-phi -> psi) -> psi
```

These are two common patterns in ND proofs that are "difficult":

- We already established some desired formula but still got open assumptions to deal with, so we apply a couple extra steps ending up with the same formula but killing some assumptions along the way.
- We open the same assumption at different points in the proof, and eventually discharge all occurrences in the same step.

Comment: Thank you, @lemontree ! I will fix the typo and read your answer carefully.

Comment: When I finish the proof: do I edit it, or paste it below again with the changes ?

Comment: Best copy-paste it so future readers can still make sense of the correction suggestions.

Comment: When you said: "After that, performing a $\lnot Elim$ with assumption $\lnot \phi$ would first lead to $\bot$", did you mean $\lnot \psi$ ?

Comment: When you said: "you have already established $\psi$ with no more open assumptions to discharge except for the antecedent of the implication", wouldn't $\lnot \psi$ labeled with sub-index 3 still undischarged, @lemontree ? What's the rule used to close that assumption ?

Comment: No. $\neg E$ on $\psi$ and $\neg \psi$ yields $\bot$. Technically $\neg A$ is just $A \to \bot$ in disguise, so $\neg E$ is a special case of $\to E$ with conclusion $\bot$. See van Dalen p. 50.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right! I overlooked that since what you have as RAA is actually $\to E$, the assumption $\neg \psi$ can not be discharged in that step. So we do need the $\neg E$ detour after all, but in a different way than what you did. I changed my answer. Good noticing!

Comment: Thank you ! Do you think it is correct, @lemontree ?

Comment: Regarding your last bullet point (in the answer): is it allowed to open the same assumption on different branches of the tree ? This is one point I do not fully understand. Specifically, I am talking about the assumption $\lnot \psi$ with sub-index 3.

Comment: Yes, it's correct now. Well done! Yes, it is allowed, as long as both are subbranches of the branch where the discharging rule is applied. From the POV of the node where the rule is applied that triggers the cancellation, you can discharge assumptions in all "children" and grandchildren etc. further up the tree, but not on "sister" branches to the left/right or "ancestors" further down the tree.

Comment: Thank you, @lemontree ! I understand what you just explained. One question: when you say "ancestors", is the tree commonly understood in an upside down manner ? I mean, the conclusion would be the father of the statement immediately above, and so on.

Comment: Well yes -- normally, mathematical trees grow upside-down, with the root (greatgreat...grandmother) of at the top, but an ND tree grows like a natural tree, so here "ancestor" means futher down in the tree.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Using quite another proof system -- apologies -- but this may help...

[image]